# Webpack + React + Loading CSS of external modules

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, webpack-style-loader

**Webpack/CSS Experts!**

My `NodeJS/React` application has the following structure, where I use `Webpack 3.8.1` to package & bundle files.

```
-app
  |--actions
  |--constants
  |--components
  |--containers
  |--css
  |--reducers
  |--store
-common
-server
-webpack
  |--rules
       |--css
       |--javascript
  |--externals
  |--paths
  |--resolve
  |--webpack.config.js
```

Everything works as expected in development and production but there is one problem that I have been struggling with: **External node modules CSS**. When I add a new dependency, which comes with some sort of CSS/SCSS/SASS stylesheets and for that matter makes use of `className` to style different components, I hit FOUC CSS where none of the external node module's CSS styles has been recognized and therefore are missing from the map that `webpack 3` creates once the build process is complete.

As an example, I am using `Material-UI` as a dependency and so far everything works but when attempting to do the following:

```
<IconButton>
    <FontIcon className="muidocs-icon-action-home"/>
</IconButton>
```

... and nothing is displayed. This is just one example and I have been facing this issue with other node modules too! So I believe there is something wrong with my `webpack` configurations or the way I am loading CSS modules. For your reference, I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinguard/8d702ddd3188fb667faedd83ab9d8205) of all `webpack` configuration files.

I have come across with some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963051/webpack-not-loading-css) but am not sure if that will help long-run as my project is becoming bigger.

Your helps & thoughts are greatly appreciated!

**[Note]** As a side note, and apart from *external* CSS modules, when I add a new CSS declaration to `main.css`, I still need to have something like:

```
import classNames from "classnames/bind";
import styles from "../../../css/components/timeline.css";
const cx = classNames.bind(styles);
```

within `import` section and later do something like this:

```
<div ref="container"
     className={cx("calendar-style")}/>
```

to have CSS styles correctly applied, which again I suspect isn't optimal. As I mentioned earlier, `webpack` creates a hashmap of all CSS styles inside a `.css` file under `public`, whose content look something like this:

```
._1zvVaiwSh1X6O03wrS2gD- {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
._2W0FVEAQcsYxEbCbWHcCE3 {
    height: 100%;
}...
```

Therefore, failing to use `cx` as stated above, will have the same problem as explained earlier and none of my CSS styles are applied. So, a following question would be: how `webpack` creates these `hashes` and why? How to control them being generated or not?

Comment: What Material-UI library are you using for React? I just did a few spikes with different React Material-UI libraries and had hell with this problem. Your CSS above looks like react-toolbox.

Comment: @Jack I am using `material-ui`. Take a look at here: http://www.material-ui.com/

Comment: Are you using the old version (material-ui.com), or the new version (material-ui-next.com)?

Comment: The old version. I actually tried their `1.0.0-beta` and it failed due to `react-group-transition/Transition not found` error so I am still on `0.19.4`. Even on the old version, when attempting to use `className`, nothing works. Only inline styling.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I'm not very familiar with the old styling as I ended up using the new beta material-ui (which uses css-in-js). I do remember having that react-group-transition/Transition error, and the fix for me was clearing my node_modules (because I started with the old version). Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Sure! Do you still have any issue with `className`s in `beta` version at all? Sounds like your `webpack` setup looks the same as mine that causes both of us having issues with `className`s. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159947/discussion-between-jack-and-kevin-ghaboosi).